# Botão do chat não habilitou nos comentários?

Tags: suporte, comentários

No domingo respondi esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/250599/14859). Já percebi que quando os comentários passam de uma determinada quantidade, ele habilita um botão "**continuar esta conversa no chat?**" porém ele não habilitou desta vez.

Já verifiquei e não encontrei uma alternativa de abrir um chat para o post, a não ser a opção de criar uma sala, posso até não ter encontrado a forma de se fazer isto na documentação (caso tenha está possibilidade me informem o link).

O que deveria ter feito? Parado os comentários? (isso se não existir uma forma de se criar este chat). Só continuei pois queria ajudá-la a resolver o problema, e a conversa ficou muito extensa.

Comment: Eu particularmente chamaria a atenção da pessoa no Estouro de Pilha, se ele participar lá

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A sugestão de chat em comentários só surge quando ambos os usuários envolvidos tem [**reputação suficiente**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) para falar em salas de bate-papo, o que não era o caso do autor da pergunta até aquele presente instante. Devido a isso, o moderador interviu e gerou a sala.

Não há muito o que se fazer nesse caso, pois o autor precisa ter no mínimo 20 de reputação e ele não tinha, então nem criando uma sala particular ele conseguiria falar, provavelmente.

O que eu posso recomendar é procurar fazer apenas perguntas objetivas que te ajudem a entender melhor problema sem alongar demais, e se perceber que está estendendo demais, sempre sugerir o autor a editar e ir adicionando toda informação adicional passada por ele na pergunta, apagar seus comentários que se tornarem irrelevantes após a edição e sinalizar os dele como "obsoleto".

Comment: obrigado, farei isto da próxima vez solicitarei edição, ou até reabertura de outra, e apagar comentários obsoletos.